# try/catch statement with a nextLine input

Tags: java, string, exception

Here I have a simple try/catch statement for an input of a string for the customers first and last names. However I need the exception to throw if a number is input or any-other non-text characters are input by the user (because names only contain text). The problem for is that a string does accept ANY characters not just text. How can I get the catch to execute if the user inputs anything but text?

```
public void Customer ()
    {
        //Variables for Customer method
        String firstName;
        String lastName;
        int customerNumber;
        boolean end = false;

        /* Reads input from user
         * Stores customers first and last name into the variable name
        */
        while(end == false)
        {
        try
            {
                System.out.println("Enter customers full name" );
                firstName = input.nextLine();

                System.out.println("Enter customers last name");
                lastName = input.nextLine();
                end = true;
            }

        catch (InputMismatchException ime)
        {
            end = false;
            System.out.println("Invalid input. You must enter the customers name. Please try again: ");
            input.next();
        }
        }   
    }
```

Comment: Use a regex to find a number in your strings.

Comment: You need to make a validator (using regex) for user input in the if condition you will check for user input in the else statement you can throw your exception InputMismatchException. So A try-catch you need to write inside try an if else. Inside else your throw exception.

Comment: Exceptions are not for controlling the flow of the program, use conditionals.

Answer (score 0):

make a `arrayList` of the String that is not in the name standard ,so do the following:

```
ArrayList< String>arrayList=new ArrayList<String>();
    arrayList.add("?");
    //add other String
    String input ="some text";
    for(int i=0;i<arrayList.size();i++){
        if(input.contains(arrayList.get(i)))
    input=input.replace(arrayList.get(i), "");
    }
```

or you could get rid of the replace part and if the condition was true ask him or her for the another try

Answer (score 0):

you can make a custom exception

```
public boolean isAlpha(String name) {
char[] chars = name.toCharArray();

for (char c : chars) {
    if(!Character.isLetter(c)) {
        return false;
    }
}

return true;
```

}

```
class InvalidException extends Exception {

    InvalidException() {
    }

    InvalidException(String message) {

  super(message);
    }

    InvalidException(String message, Throwable cause) {

  super(message, cause);
    }
}
```

public void Customer ()
    {
        //Variables for Customer method
        String firstName;
        String lastName;
        int customerNumber;
        boolean end = false;

```
    while(end == false)
    {
    try
        {
            System.out.println("Enter customers full name" );
            firstName = input.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter customers last name");
            lastName = input.nextLine();
    if(isAplha(lastname)){

    }
    else
    {
    throw new InvalidException("Your message here");
    }
            end = true;
        }

    catch (InputMismatchException ime)
    {
        end = false;
        System.out.println("Invalid input. You must enter the customers name. Please try again: ");
        input.next();
    }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*if regex seems too high profile for you right now , you can use an character array to formulate the string ...
for each character array entry , you can check `with isNumber() , isDigit and so on.`..
however when i recommended this answer once before , a senior member said-" he would beat his own right hand with his left hand if his right hand wrote this code" :P*